# duplicated operator(or attribute) on the same input control - v-model and @change

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I wrote a code like below - It is `nuxt.js`, which is one of the Vue frameworks. This code will be expected to

- When change event triggered, update `data` value. There would be some logic to alter passed data
- At the same time, it connected with `data` value to apply input box changing

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- I got question here -->
    <input type="text" ref="receiver" @change="applyData('receiver')" v-model="deliveryInfo.receiver" />
    <button type="button" @click="test">TEST</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        deliveryInfo: {
          receiver: ''
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      applyData: function (refName) {
        let ref = this.$refs[refName];
        if (ref) {
          let temp = {};
          temp[refName] = ref.value;
          this.applyAddress(temp);
        } else {
          console.log("There is no " + refName + " in this.$refs");
        }
      },
      applyAddress: function (options) {
        this.deliveryInfo = Object.assign({}, this.deliveryInfo, options);
        this.$emit('applyChildData', this.deliveryInfo);
      },

      test: function () {
          console.log('set John Doe');
        this.deliveryInfo = Object.assign({}, this.deliveryInfo, {receiver: 'John Doe'});
        console.log('After change ', this.deliveryInfo);
        // It triggers applyData method and change input element value
        // But when I remove v-model in input value, it is not working
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And it works as expected.

However, using `v-model` and `@change` at the same tag looks weird to me since both of tag manipulates the connected value(in this case, it would be `deliveryInfo.receiver`)

Is this code OK to use in production project?
Thanks!

FYI, in my real case, it applied to a phone number. I want to show a phone number without dashes in a browser, but data should be saved with dashes.

So when people type in the input, `@change` alter data to insert dashes.

Comment: The point is `@change` and `v-model` at the same time is OK or not. I comment this since it seems the point of the post is not clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##Responding to Your question
This is good use of [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) and `Object.assign()` but normally this would be a good place to use a [watched Property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers), or if you need to add dashes, a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

Take a look at the example below, which uses a watcher, instead of the `@onchange`, which means that the method `applyData()` can be eliminated:

```js
const form = new Vue({
    el: '#form',
    data: function () {
      return {
        deliveryInfo: {
          receiver: ''
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      'deliveryInfo.receiver': function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('receiver changed - deliveryinfo:', this.deliveryInfo);
        this.$emit('applyChildData', this.deliveryInfo);
      }
    },
    methods: {
      test: function () {
          console.log('set John Doe');
        this.deliveryInfo = Object.assign({}, this.deliveryInfo, {receiver: 'John Doe'});
        console.log('After change ', this.deliveryInfo);
        // It triggers applyData method and change input element value
        // But when I remove v-model in input value, it is not working
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

  <div id="form">
    <!-- I got question here -->
    <input type="text" ref="receiver" v-model="deliveryInfo.receiver" /><!--@change="applyData('receiver')"-->
    <button type="button" @click="test">TEST</button>
  </div>
```

Or the snippet below which uses a computed property to add a dash between the third and fourth characters...

```js
const form = new Vue({
    el: '#form',
    data: function () {
      return {
        deliveryInfo: {
          receiver: ''
        }
      }
    },
    computed: {
      dashedReceiver: function() {
        if (this.deliveryInfo.receiver.length > 3) {
          return this.deliveryInfo.receiver.slice(0,3) + '-' + this.deliveryInfo.receiver.slice(3);
        }
        return this.deliveryInfo.receiver;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

  <div id="form">
    <!-- I got question here -->
    <input type="text" ref="receiver" v-model="deliveryInfo.receiver" />
    <div>{{dashedReceiver}}</div>
  </div>
```

###Other feedback
One other critique I have is this line:

> ```
> let ref = this.$refs[refName];
> ```

That variable never gets re-assigned so to avoid accidental re-assignment, use `const` instead of `let`. There are some who recommend the following:

> - use `const` by default

- only use `let` if rebinding is needed
  <sup>[1](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-const)</sup>

There may not be much of a performance difference here although after reading some SO answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50808097/1575353) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40070682/1575353) there is a potential but that might only be if a primitive type value (e.g. `42`) was used.

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-const</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, I got one more question from your reply. You mentioned the keywords, `let` and `const`. I agree with yours since the variable will be never assigned after initial assign, but is there any other reasons to use `const` without semantical reasons? like performance...

Comment: I have updated my answer to respond to your question